# Black pixels not coming completely black?

Tags: java, image, java-2d, pixel

SO I'm trying to make an image consisting only of black and white pixels. My problem is that when I zoom in and see I can view some grey pixels around the black, as a kind of transition type thing to the white. How /why is this happening?

This is the code that's producing the image:

```
public class DrawByPixelData extends JPanel{

Image img;

public DrawByPixelData(){

    int w = 10;
    int h = 10;

    int pixels[] = new int[w*h];

    for(int i=0;i<w*h;i++){
        if(i%7==0)
            pixels[i]=0xff000000;
            else
            pixels[i]=0xffffffff;
    }

    img = createImage(new MemoryImageSource(w,h,pixels,0,w));

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);
}

public void saveTheImage(){

    SaveImageData sv = new SaveImageData();
    sv.SaveImage(img);
 }
```

And the code saving the image:

```
public class SaveImageData {

public void SaveImage(Image img){

    BufferedImage image = toBufferedImage(img);
    save(image, "jpg");
}

private BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img) {

    int w = img.getWidth(null);
    int h = img.getHeight(null);

    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY;
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(w,h,type);
    Graphics2D g2 = dest.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose();

    return dest;
}

private static void save(BufferedImage bi, String ext){

    String fileName = "New";
    File file = new File(fileName+"."+ext);

    try {
        ImageIO.write(bi, ext, file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Image didn't write: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Is it because of the format that I've saved in? Or some kind of color model thing?

This is the image produced. You can see the greyish pixels as well.

[image]

Thanks.

Image after changing to png and using anti aliasing off:

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing the grey pixels in that tiny image, or when you zoom it in the browser?

Comment: Ok, so opening in an editing software, and using anti aliasing and a loss less format, I'm able to see the pixels as they should be, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two things that might be happening: Anti-aliasing, and JPEG lossy artefacts.

1. [Anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) is where you soften a border between colors by drawing intermediate pixels between them in a mix of the two colors.
2. [JPEG images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression) are usually *lossy*, which means that they're compressed and the compression may well anti-alias boundaries to make them less apparent.

I don't immediately see anything in your code that's doing anti-aliasing on purpose (it's frequently a useful technique) but I'm not sure what the `Graphics2D` defaults are so you might want to check that out and possibly explicitly turn anti-aliasing off (see the discussion at the top of [the documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)). And when saving, look at saving as a GIF or PNG, which are lossless formats.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent anti-aliasing from happening? Or do is it just the format?

Comment: @Achint: I just edited the answer, I'm not sure what the `Graphics2D` defaults are so you might want to explicitly turn anti-aliasing off with [`setRenderingHint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint(java.awt.RenderingHints.Key,%20java.lang.Object)). But I think you'll want to use GIF or PNG anyway, because of the lossyness of JPG.

Comment: Hye, thanks! But there's no visible difference by applying those things. Could it be something else? Isn't there some way to make clear cut pixels?

Comment: @Achint: Can you post the resulting GIF or PNG?

Comment: @Achint: I don't see any anti-aliasing in the PNG file you uploaded. It could be the tool you're using to zoom into it. I'm using GIMP, and at 1600% mag I don't see any grey pixels (I do see a few -- not many -- in the JPG).

Comment: Yeah, I was using Windows Picture Viewer to see, that was showing grey pixels. Using paint shows no grey for the png.

Comment: @Achint: Good deal, glad that helped. FWIW, I just tried your code locally, and just changing it from JPG to PNG did the trick here. That said, there's no harm in making your intent explicit by actively turning off anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers automatically apply antialising when zooming: it's not a problem of the image, you are just visualizing it the wrong way.

Try opening it in an image editor like Photoshop or GIMP. No grey pixels should appear.

Comment: So you mean even if I use Windows picture viewer, it will automatically apply it?

Comment: There are really some grey pixels in the JPG. Not the PNG, though, that was indeed the viewer he was using.

Comment: Yeah the JPEG format will also apply noise since it's a lossy format, but we've been over that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are writing the image as a JPEG file, which is a lossy format. Its compression is built for photos, not images with sharp color boundaries. Its compression will create faint "aliasing" on these borders which is what you are seeing. You almost surely want a lossless indexed format like PNG.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Changing the extension type to PNG still produces the softening around the pixels on zooming in. Is there anything else that I could be doing wrong, or can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not confirmed it through your code, but it sounds like your image is being anti-aliased / compressed; both of which is supported within JPEG encoding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing

> In computer graphics, anti aliasing improves the appearance of polygon edges, so they are not "jagged", but smoothed out on the screen. However, it incurs a performance cost for the graphics card and uses more video memory. The level of anti-aliasing determines how smooth polygon edges are (and how much video memory it consumes).

You can enable/disable Anti Aliasing on the Graphics2D object:

```
 ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, // Anti-alias!
     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

For the full code: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AntiAlias.htm

I also advise you output the file as a PNG to ensure that the JPEG compression isn't also playing a part:

```
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
```

For the full code: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! Turning the anti aliasing off and changing to png isn't making a any visible difference. Isn't there a way that I can produced images with clear cut pixel differences?

Comment: If it's not anti-aliasing or compression, I'm not sure where the blurred pixels are coming from.